# What was the correct thing to do in this review?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, link-only-answers

I've been learning to go through the review queue, and this one popped up:

[Entity Framework Code First: pre generated views work, but startup is still slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079833/entity-framework-code-first-pre-generated-views-work-but-startup-is-still-slow)

The answer given was a link to the correct answer on an external site.

I tried to leave a comment saying "please include this in the post", but it popped up an error about failing to add the comment, so I just upvoted it, since the answer *was* correct and useful, and at that point I got a "STOP. This was an audit and you failed." and I saw that someone else had posted the comment that I was trying to post and there was one downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the *Low Quality Posts* queue, you should **Recommend Deletion** and pick **This is a link-only answer (and not spam)**. This will automatically add a comment to the answer:

> “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

In the *First Posts* and *Late Answers* queue, you should flag it with the **it is not an answer** reason.

But watch out, some link answers are good answers. Read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for more information.

Comment: So it's better for there to be no answer at all that for there to be a suboptimal answer that could be edited?

Comment: @o11c Sometimes these answers get converted to comments on the question, but I don't know how the 10k tools / moderator tools work in this regard. The author can always post a new answer, one that doesn't contain just a link.